# Is there a reminder service which can be seamlessly integrated between alexa, pc and mobile?

Tags: notifications, alexa-skills-kit, reminders

I am looking for a service

- which can take reminders through alexa, pc(debian, mac or windows)
  and mobile (android or iOS).
- should be able to dispatch notifications
- should sync between devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today there is not. However, I know that Urban Airship is working on that. Here is a link to their announcement about it.

https://www.urbanairship.com/blog/voice-notification-early-access-program